# My JUnit Test keeps failing one of my methods and I do not understand why

Tags: java, methods, junit, tostring

The JUnit test keeps failing my addScore method, however I know for sure that the scores were added, which means that most likely my toString maybe wrong. However I cannot figure out what is wrong with it. Please Help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GradeBook
{
   private double[] scores;
   private int scoresSize;

   /**
      Constructs a gradebook with no scores and a given capacity.
      @capacity the maximum number of scores in this gradebook
   */
   public GradeBook(int capacity)
   {
      scores = new double[capacity];
      scoresSize = 0;
   }

   /**
      Adds a score to this gradebook.
      @param score the score to add
      @return true if the score was added, false if the gradebook is full
   */
   public boolean addScore(double score)
   {
      if (scoresSize < scores.length)
      {
         scores[scoresSize] = score;
         scoresSize++;
         return true;
      }
      else
         return false;      
   }

   /**
      Computes the sum of the scores in this gradebook.
      @return the sum of the scores
   */
   public double sum()
   {
      double total = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < scoresSize; i++)
      {
         total = total + scores[i];
      }
      return total;
   }

   /**
      Gets the minimum score in this gradebook.
      @return the minimum score, or 0 if there are no scores.
   */
   public double minimum()
   {
      if (scoresSize == 0) return 0;
      double smallest = scores[0];
      for (int i = 1; i < scoresSize; i++)
      {
         if (scores[i] < smallest)
         {
            smallest = scores[i];
         }
      }
      return smallest;
   }

   /**
      Gets the final score for this gradebook.
      @return the sum of the scores, with the lowest score dropped if 
      there are at least two scores, or 0 if there are no scores.
   */
   public double finalScore() 
   {
      if (scoresSize == 0)
         return 0;
      else if (scoresSize == 1)
         return scores[0];
      else
         return sum() - minimum();
   }

   /**
    * Gets the score size from the GradeBook
    * @param scoresSize The score size
    * @return scoresSize The score size
    */
   public int getScoreSize(int scoresSize){
       return scoresSize;
   }

   public String toString(){

       String out = null;
       for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
           out += (Double.toString(scores[i]) + " ");   
       }
       return out;
   }
}
```

That is the main class and now the JUnit test;

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


public class GradeBookTest {

    GradeBook g1;
    GradeBook g2;
    GradeBook g3;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        g1 = new GradeBook(5);
        g1.addScore(50);
        g1.addScore(43);
        g1.addScore(22);
        g1.addScore(4);
        g1.addScore(100);

        g2 = new GradeBook(5);
        g2.addScore(43);
        g2.addScore(34);
        g2.addScore(67);
        g2.addScore(82);
        g2.addScore(97);

        g3 = new GradeBook(5);
        g3.addScore(13);
        g3.addScore(25);
        g3.addScore(90);
        g3.addScore(78);
        g3.addScore(100);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        g1 = null;
        g2 = null;
        g3 = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddScore() {
        assertTrue(g1.toString().equals("50.0 43.0 22.0 4.0 100.0 "));
        assertTrue(g2.toString().equals("43.0 34.0 67.0 82.0 97.0 "));
        assertTrue(g3.toString().equals("13.0 25.0 90.0 78.0 100.0 "));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSum() {
        assertEquals(219, g1.sum(), .0001);
        assertEquals(323, g2.sum(), .0001);
        assertEquals(306, g3.sum(), .0001);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMinimum() {
        assertEquals(4, g1.minimum(), .001);
        assertEquals(34, g2.minimum(), .001);
        assertEquals(13, g3.minimum(), .001);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFinalScore() {
        assertEquals(215, g1.finalScore(), .0001);
        assertEquals(289, g2.finalScore(), .0001);
        assertEquals(293, g3.finalScore(), .0001);
    }


}
```

Comment: Is it testAddScore that's failing? If you did a System.out.println(g1), what would it print?

Comment: It is testAddScore that is failing, and when I did that nothing printed. I know that it adds because it passes all other tests, so it clearly adds and understands them.

Comment: It fails on the first asserTrue in the testCase

Comment: Before your first line in testAddScore, add System.out.println(g1.toString()) to see what the system prints. (It's not what you put in the assert.)

Comment: Among other possible problems, you added `50 43 22 4...` but your assertion is `50 4 32 24...`

Comment: That was my bad in rushing, that is fixed, but not the main problem

Comment: null50.0 43.0 22.0 4.0 100.0      that is what prints out, I'm guessing that null is causing problems. And it's because it was initialized like that?

Answer (score 1):

Found where the problem was.

I had initialized my string variable in the toString() assignment to null and added to that value.

Once I changed that, my program worked.

Comment: So you changed the initialization to `String out = "";` or some such?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Double.toString(100) does not necessarily result in 100.  Converting double values to strings in Java will usually include a decimal point and some digits after.

Here is an example program to prove the point:

```
public class DoubleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Double.toString(100));
    }
}
```

Because of this, you have several options:

1. change your `toString` method to output double values with a known format (using java.text.NumberFormat for instance), or
2. change your `testAddScore` test to construct a different expected strings
3. avoid using `toString` all together for assertions and assert the values in the collection instead.

Comment: I changed my output to match with decimals, however it still failed.

Comment: Or use `BigDecimal` instead of `double` to get rid of the rounding errors.

Comment: It was the null initialization in the toString method